# LT3546 voltage unstable at low current

Tags: voltage, dc-dc-converter

I am using this IC in my design as 3.3V power supply. My design basically has 2 variation. So design1, has a few more circuits powered by the 3.3V. and design2 has less circuits. Following the application circuit, I changed the R1 and R2 and C1 as needed to set the output to 3.3V

[image]

design1&2: R1=137K R2=30K C1=47pF L1=1.0mH

So from calculation, Vfb2 is set to 0.6V, and output is 3.3V. What I don't get it after a while, for design2 (with lower current consumption ~100mA), the Vfb suddenly goes up, and subsequently, Vcc also end up to be 3.4~3.5V. This does not happen in design1 (high current consumption ~500mA).

Does anybody has any idea why this is so?

Answer (score 1):

Burst mode operation starts below 0.24A in the standard circuit configuration that you are showing for better light load efficiency. But this also leads to a higher output ripple and could potentially be your problem. You can disable burst mode by grounding the BMC pin or set the MODE pin to a different voltage to switch to pulse skipping or forced conduction modes. Have another look at the datasheet.

If you are using the tssop package you could try to test disabling burst mode by slightly bending up the offending BMC pin and attaching a small wire to gnd.